# In a small list on mobile, how to manage a simple filter?

Tags: mobile-application, filter, listview

In a simple list, 4 types of a specific variable can be displayed.

Which is better?
Check the list and display only available variables in the filter, or all the filters shows, and if there is no item, should the blank list be displayed?

For example, as shown in Figure 1, there is no type 3 in the list below.

[image: fig1- list]

**There are now two ways to display the filter:**

1. Show in the list of filters and if you select Show empty list error. (*fig2*)

[image: fig2 - with type3]

2. Remove this item from the list of filters and display the filter without item 3. (*fig3*)

[image: fig3 - without type3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest keeping the empty option in the filters, so users know that it is an option (even if it is empty at this moment). This would be to minimize confusion.

I like the empty state when clicking on the empty option, but it does require an extra tap to find out it is empty. If this was a webshop, I wouldn't want to find out the item in my cart is out of stock the moment I am checking out. I would want to see a visual feedback of this before I even add it to my cart.

Therefore, a solution could be to give the users that kind of visual feedback:

---

**Option 1**

Add the number of results inside the filter option itself, to provide a clear expectation instead of disappointment (and frustration due to unnecessary taps)

[image]

**Option 2**

Make the empty filter option not-clickable (disabled) to tell the user there are no results for this filter option. Making this option 'disabled' prevents unnecessary taps.

[image]

**Option 3**

A combination of the two: Add the number of results in the filter option and also make it 'disabled'. Inspired by online clothing/shoe stores, where the unavailable sizes/colors are shown very clearly with lower opacity or even a bold line diagonally across the box.

[image]

---

### **Conclusion**

I personally think option 2 is preferable over option 1, because lowering the opacity is a quicker visual feedback than adding extra text that has to be read first. Option 3 is great because it also shows the positive numbers for other filter options which is super helpful, but does increase the amount of text/'clutter', which is not ideal if you want to keep your design minimalistic. The decision is up to you as the designer ;)

Comment: Thank you.
Your solutions were very interesting and helpful for me. I Agree with you that option 3 is great!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **Option 1**.

If the Filter 1,2,3,4 is a constant, it is better to have them fixed rather than having any removed if the data is empty.

It is better to display the empty state message so user will understand that there is no data for the filter.